# Cache big PHP files in client browser - status '200 ok' instead of '304 not modified' - Apache

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, http, caching

I modified the `.htaccess` at root like that:

```
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresDefault "access plus 300 seconds"

ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType text/javascript "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/jpg "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access plus 1 day"
ExpiresByType text/php "access plus 1 day"
ExpiresByType text/html "access plus 1 day"
```

I also added those lines to the Apache file configuration (`httpd.conf`):

```
LoadModule expires_module modules/mod_expires.so
LoadModule headers_module modules/mod_headers.so
LoadModule deflate_module modules/mod_deflate.so
```

But browser doesn't seem to cache the `katalog.php`.

[image: click to see image]

I tried to change headers via the php but it just crashed the file, I couldn't access it.

I would like to cache it with "no-cache" (to check if it's still the same) because it takes time to download it every time (13.3MB ...), even when user press "backspace" button...

Comment: whats the content type of response for katalog.php?

Comment: you want to cache php script like static files ???

Comment: Roland : it is a big table - around 1500 rows and 25 columns

Comment: jsxqf : I want to cache the result, yes, so when the users go back to this page and it hasnt been modified (I mean no rows have been deleted or added)  it doesnt reload the page completely ( and then it avoids downloading those 13MB)

Comment: You are aware that caching is being suppressed by default while you have the developer tools open…? You can change that in the tool settings…

Comment: @deceze Oh no I didn't know, I will check taht, thanks

Comment: PHP sends its own caching headers, you can not overwrite that via Apache configuration. Send the headers from within your PHP script, that is the easiest solution.

Comment: @Cbroe Ok I thought that I could do it.
I've found that : http://www.jonasjohn.de/snippets/php/caching.htm
I will try it

Answer (score 0):

Finally managed to cache this big html content 
I used this : jonasjohn.de/snippets/php/caching.htm
(without using e-tag) and apcu php extension to store an application scoped variable. ( to check if katalog has been updated : I compare the app scoped varaible to a $_session variable , if they're the same I dont load the content)